# Slicing multiple ranges of columns in Pandas, by list of names

Tags: python, pandas, slice

I am trying to select multiple columns in a Pandas dataframe in two different approaches:

1)via the columns number, for examples, columns 1-3 and columns 6 onwards.

and

2)via a list of column names, for instance:

```
years = list(range(2000,2017))
months = list(range(1,13))
years_month = list(["A", "B", "B"])
for y in years:
    for m in months:
        y_m = str(y) + "-" + str(m)
        years_month.append(y_m)
```

Then, **years_month** would produce the following:

```
['A',
 'B',
 'C',
 '2000-1',
 '2000-2',
 '2000-3',
 '2000-4',
 '2000-5',
 '2000-6',
 '2000-7',
 '2000-8',
 '2000-9',
 '2000-10',
 '2000-11',
 '2000-12',
 '2001-1',
 '2001-2',
 '2001-3',
 '2001-4',
 '2001-5',
 '2001-6',
 '2001-7',
 '2001-8',
 '2001-9',
 '2001-10',
 '2001-11',
 '2001-12']
```

That said, what is the best(or correct) way to load only the columns in which the names are in the list **years_month** in the two approaches?

Comment: Not sure I get what you're asking.  If you have a list of column names, you can select those columns with `df[my_list]`.

Comment: Thanks but it does not work for me this way.

Comment: Then please show your code.  You say your question is about pandas, but your code doesn't use pandas at all.  Show what you're trying to do with pandas.

Comment: Your question asks about a list of column names, yet you accepted an answer with a list of column indices; which is it? (Mind you in this case there was a fairly simple mapping, but that's not the general case. So this can't be used as a canonical question.)

Comment: You can create all of `years_month` with a **list comprehension** : `['%s-%s' % (y,m) for y in years for m in months]` . (That's actually a nested list comprehension)

Comment: Hence you could reduce all your code to `['A','B','C'] + ['%s-%s' % (y,m) for y in range(2000,2017) for m in range(1,13)]`

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I think you need [`numpy.r_`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.r_.html) for concanecate positions of columns, then use [`iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html) for selecting:

```
print (df.iloc[:, np.r_[1:3, 6:len(df.columns)]])
```

and for second approach subset by `list`:

```
print (df[years_month])
```

Sample:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'2000-1':[1,3,5],
                   '2000-2':[5,3,6],
                   '2000-3':[7,8,9],
                   '2000-4':[1,3,5],
                   '2000-5':[5,3,6],
                   '2000-6':[7,8,9],
                   '2000-7':[1,3,5],
                   '2000-8':[5,3,6],
                   '2000-9':[7,4,3],
                   'A':[1,2,3],
                   'B':[4,5,6],
                   'C':[7,8,9]})

print (df)
   2000-1  2000-2  2000-3  2000-4  2000-5  2000-6  2000-7  2000-8  2000-9  A  \
0       1       5       7       1       5       7       1       5       7  1   
1       3       3       8       3       3       8       3       3       4  2   
2       5       6       9       5       6       9       5       6       3  3   

   B  C  
0  4  7  
1  5  8  
2  6  9  

print (df.iloc[:, np.r_[1:3, 6:len(df.columns)]])
   2000-2  2000-3  2000-7  2000-8  2000-9  A  B  C
0       5       7       1       5       7  1  4  7
1       3       8       3       3       4  2  5  8
2       6       9       5       6       3  3  6  9
```

---

You can also sum of `ranges` (cast to `list` in `python 3` is necessary):

```
rng = list(range(1,3)) + list(range(6, len(df.columns)))
print (rng)
[1, 2, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11]

print (df.iloc[:, rng])
   2000-2  2000-3  2000-7  2000-8  2000-9  A  B  C
0       5       7       1       5       7  1  4  7
1       3       8       3       3       4  2  5  8
2       6       9       5       6       3  3  6  9
```

Comment: Thanks Jezrael, but I was wondering how to do this without importing an additional module. Thanks for the insight!

Comment: If use `pandas`, `numpy` is required dependencies see http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/install.html#dependencies. So only use `import pandas as pd`,  `import numpy as np`

Comment: I add pure python solution, please check edited answer.

Comment: @Guga, you can use Pandas's NumPy: `pd.np.r_[]` ;)

Comment: @MaxU - Thank you for comment

Answer (score 2):

I’m not sure what exactly you are asking but in general [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) allows you to select by label, [`DataFrame.iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html) by index.

For example selecting columns # 0, 1 and 4:

```
dataframe.iloc[:, [0, 1, 4]]
```

and selecting columns labelled 'A', 'B' and 'C':

```
dataframe.loc[:, ['A', 'B', 'C']]
```

Comment: That is partially what I was looking for. I want to be able to slice the columns I want to keep using the numbers of the columns, instead of their names.

Comment: The type of slicing you mention I am aware of. However, I want to be able to slice multiple rows  such as: colums [1:3] and columns [10:20].

Comment: If you want a slice of the row you can use `df.iloc[:,3:]` to select everything after and including the third column.