# python pandas slice column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas data structure with a shape of (500, 19).

```
dataset1 = pandas.read_csv(url, sep = ";", header = 0)
```

How can I slice the data vertically?

**Example:**

```
1,2,3
4,5,6
7,8,9
```

`dataset1['slicing function to get second column']` yields:

```
2
5
8
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html) function but python counts from `0`, so for second column need `1`:

```
print (df.iloc[:, 1])
0    2
1    5
2    8
Name: 1, dtype: int64
```

For range:

```
print (df.iloc[:, 0:3])
   0  1  2
0  1  2  3
1  4  5  6
2  7  8  9
```

Comment: How to slice a range of column? eg. column 1-3

Comment: How can i slice two sets of ranges? eg. column 1-2 and 5-6

Comment: You need `r_` function, check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40698095/2901002)