# Split CSV file Columns into multiple files with iloc

Tags: python, csv

I have a CSV file which contains 98 columns(for now) which have columns from other files I just want to split the other files' columns into new CSV file just like this...

I have a csv file uploaded here with name   [GenerateAndSplitSeedFile(Parts_skills_predict).csv](https://pyfiddle.io/fiddle/f0f17dc7-f748-4bf7-9212-989bbec06f16/?m=Uploaded%20file(s)), look at it if you want.

```
data =pd.read_csv('MergedSeedData(Parts_skills_Durations_fix).csv')
print(len(data.columns))
data1 = data.drop(data.iloc[:, 64:], axis=1)
print(data1)
data1.to_csv('data1file.csv', index=False)
```

Here I'm reading the CSV file and I'm getting the only 64 columns from 98 columns and writing it to the CSV file.

**Again same operations for other split, here I need to get columns from (0 - 8) and from (64 - 83) for that I have done here is:**

```
data22 = data.drop(data.iloc[:, 8:64], axis=1)
data2 = data22.drop(data22.iloc[:, 19:], axis=1)
# print(data2)
data2.to_csv('datafile.csv', index=False)
```

Here I have splitted the columns from 0-8 and 64-98 in first split(data22) and then drop the extra columns from data2

**Question is, how to make the split for data2 in single line I want to split the columns from 0-8,64-83 from main file which total of 98 columns I need to write in a single line...**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Slicing multiple ranges of columns in Pandas, by list of names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40698043/slicing-multiple-ranges-of-columns-in-pandas-by-list-of-names)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple ways of doing it:

1.) [np.concatenate](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/generated/numpy.concatenate.html) and [np.arange](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.arange.html)

```
#selecting 0-8,64-83
data.iloc[:, np.concatenate((np.arange(0,8),np.arange(64,83)),axis=0))]
#This is generate a list of column indexes you want to choose
```

2) [np.r_](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.r_.html)

```
data.iloc[:, np.r_[0:8,64:83]]
```

Comment: i''m not able to get the correct columns in my csv file there is no columns from 0-8 its also taking till last column that i don't want

Comment: @snehilsingh I suggest you select columns using above approach(you can put any range you want ) instead of dropping them and losing information.

Comment: Is it possible that we can read the string column names itself otherthan selecting columns index please ping me if know this....thnx