# How to subset dataframe using pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I wanted to subset columns which may or may not be adjacent to each other. In this pilot case, there are only 39 columns, so writing out full column names are possible but tedious. What I'm trying to do is only subset column based on indices.

```
df_sub = df.iloc[:,[10,11,29:37]]
```

But I get this error:

```
File "<ipython-input-46-d9362578c302>", line 1
    df_sub = df.iloc[:,[10,11,29:37]]
                                ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Isn't there a way to subset columns with column indices which may not be next to each other?

Searching on google to do something like this only showed me methods on subsetting based on column names, index that are next to each other, or entering each indices separately e.g., [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/indexing-and-selecting-data-with-pandas/). What if there's a mixture with 100s of columns?

Comment: I won't recommend this: `[10,11,*list(range(29,37))]` <-- this can be written like this

Comment: That's one quick answer. Thanks, @Pygirl. What's the recommended way?

Comment: Actually I can think of this only right now. There must be some other better way. Waiting for other answers.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40698043/slicing-multiple-ranges-of-columns-in-pandas-by-list-of-names

Comment: Yes. @Ch3steR , "slicing" is the term I missed. That maybe why I had a bit difficulty finding the answer. re-learnt something today.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
g = lambda x,y: range(x,y)

[10,11,*g(29,37)]
```

---

```
#[10, 11, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36]
```

---

**Time Comparison:**

```
%%timeit -n 1000000
np.r_[10,11,29:37]
```

> 12.4 µs ± 123 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)

```
%%timeit -n 1000000
g = lambda x,y: range(x,y)
[10,11,*g(29,37)]
```

> 338 ns ± 3.94 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops
> each)

Comment: Is there a reason you don't recommend the code you put in the comments? slow? side effects?

Comment: @user1828605: I wasn't sure about its performance but it seems faster.

Comment: I mean, we're taking a few microseconds here. The only computational cost being analyzed, is whatever overhead there may be of calling a numpy function